# Codeigniter / PHP - A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, css, codeigniter, mvc

Estou tentando realizar uma página de pesquisa, mas ao inserir qualquer informação no input e pressionar enter, recebo esta mensagem:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable

Filename: views/pesquisa.php

Line Number: 60

Backtrace:
```

Model:

```
   class Busca_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function buscar($busca)
    {
        if(empty($busca))
        {
            return array();
        }

        $busca = $this->input->post("busca");
        $this->db->like("marca", $busca);
        return $this->db->get("lista_carros")->result_array();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("carros_model", '', TRUE);
    }


    public function gravar()
    {
        $info = $this->input->post();
    
        $id=$this->carros_model->gravar($info);
        return $id;
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('dashboard');
    }


    public function cadastro()
    {
        $this->load->view('cadastro');
    }


    public function lista()
    {
        $info = $this->input->post();
        if ($info) {
            print_r($info);
        } else {
            $data['listagem'] = $this->carros_model->listar();
        }
        $this->load->view('lista', $data);
        $this->load->model("busca_model", '', TRUE);
    }


    public function deletar()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        $this->load->model("busca_model", '', TRUE);
        $retorno = $this->carros_model->deletar($post);

        // passos: enviar para a model para fazer a exclusão
        // em seguida, caso sucesso, vc vai enviar um parametro de sucesso ou erro
        if ($retorno == true) {
            $dados['error'] = 0;
            $dados['msg'] = "Carro deletado com sucesso";
        } else {
            $dados['error'] = 1;
            $dados['msg_error'] = "Erro ao deletar o carro escolhido";
        }
        echo json_encode($dados);
    }

    public function pesquisar()
    {
        $this->load->model("carros_model", '', TRUE);
        $this->load->model("busca_model");
        $this->load->view('pesquisa');
        $data["listagem"] = $this->busca_model->buscar($_POST);
        // print_r($data);
        // exit();
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $this->load->model("carros_model");
        $data["carro"] = $this->carros_model->show($id);
        print_r($data);
        exit();
        $this->load->view("formulario");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Dentro da sua Model você esta esperando um id "busca"

```
$busca = $this->input->post("busca");
```

Porém não existe, porque nos eu controller você está passando o $_POST direto:

```
$data["listagem"] = $this->busca_model->buscar($_POST);
```

Tente trocar por isso:

```
$data["listagem"] = $this->busca_model->buscar($_POST['busca']);
```

Isso, imaginando que da sua view você manda o id 'busca'

Como está sua view ?